# Retrofit 2.0.0-beta ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3 How do I resolve this to retrieve track? - using Soundcloud API

Tags: java, eclipse, soundcloud, retrofit2

I have been doing [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/develop-music-streaming-android-app/).

But I cant seem to get the app running. After hours of trying to fix the errors, I have pinpointed it to this line in my MainActivity.Java `SCService scService = SoundCloud.getService();` (just to point out I am a bit inexperienced when it comes to Java errors).

So I decided to create a little program to test whether the API calls is retrieving and anything(I'm trying to get the track from my soundcloud account)

```
import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.Retrofit;
import retrofit.http.GET;

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.soundcloud.com/").build();

        SCService service = retrofit.create(SCService.class);

        System.out.println("Welcome boi");

        System.out.println(service.me().toString());
    }

    public interface SCService {
        @GET("tracks?client_id=" + Config.CLIENT_ID)

        Callme();
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio/Source
at retrofit.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:301)
at com.casula.testingapp.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:12)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okio.Source
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
```

Please help I think it has something to do with my Retrofit.jar library. I'm using Retrofit2.0.0-3beta and Eclipse IDE - How do I fix this to be able to retrieve the track from my account?

Comment: use Android Studio. I think Retrofit needs okhttp which itself needs okio. In AS this dependency tree is managed automatically. For eclipse, you need to manually include the okhttp and okio jars.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bart. At university, I used the Eclipse IDE for everything for this reason alone I did not want to move over to AS for my android project. I have started using it and it is great! build.gradle makes life easier

Comment: I meant to Thank eriuzo, sorry I'm still new to this...